# the request failed with http status 401 unauthorized. web service on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have web service hosted in IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have WebService url say

> http://tempweb/temp/MasterData.asmx

If i try to call the webservice from local machine then it allows me to do so.
 But if I try to call it from server browser or from IIS hosted code then it does not allow me to call.Getting the request failed with http status 401 unauthorized. 
If I set Authentication of webservice virtual directory to anonymous then it works, but I don't want to make it anonymous as Windows Authentication is being used.
I tried following code also, but no luck.

```
        wspdasmaster = new pdasmasterref.MasterData();
        wspdasmaster.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        wspdasmaster.PreAuthenticate = true;
        wspdasmaster.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

How can I resove this issue?

Comment: You need to setup a service account and use it for connecting to web service. Also, you have to set the service account in App Pool / IIS.

Comment: Can you provide me any reference link for this? I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: Your server engineer might be able to help you on setting up the service account and configuring it in DB, IIS (App Pool)... there are several useful links online: 1) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd548356(v=WS.10).aspx 2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649309.aspx